# google app script took too long to respond and field to serve web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have Google app script deployed as web app it works will first time, but it is broken now

here are steps to regenerate the problem

1. create two files `code.js` and `Index.html`

```js
function doGet() {
  Logger.log("endpoint is executed!");
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, World!
  </body>
</html>
```

2. deploy as web apps and authorize anyone with link [live link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzjh3j1_uB_BdTr0FIGRALxEaLhifpd5VhHlpE_70cFz741x6g90vVsINqrCoYBUb0/exec)

**Problem** when I go to the link took too long to respond with this error in console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: loadTimeData is not defined at HTMLDocument.onDocumentLoad

However, the logs on server side says [all things are correctly Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62SPq.png)

I was thought it's a Google server fault and will recover after some time, but it still exists more than 5 day!

I am new to the Google app script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not Loading Web Apps

Hi! Welcome on using Google Apps Script. I have accessed your live link and it seems that it shows that it works already.

For starters the error it seems that it is calling a function that is not included in your current code which brings 2 things. Incorrectly named files or the deployment is not yet updated.

If it still exist on your machine I suggest try to do a basic trouble shooting like clearing cache and cookies (please be careful with this one as important information might be affected during the clearing).

### Screenshot of your Live Link during access

[image]

If you have further question or any hurdles along the way the feel free to ask additional questions.

Comment: Thanks for mansion that it works on your machine .... I have been facing the most wired bug, it's from my Internet service provider !!!! I connect my machine to mobile data instead of DSL, it works !!

Comment: I understand though I think it is an isolated case.  Maybe it is worth raising to your ISP and also  here https://issuetracker.google.com/ they might be able to figure out the root cause and fix this.